# how do I change this query from SQL Server 2016 to MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

This is a sample of a query that I currently use regularly in SQL Server 2016 (Standard edition).  I need assistance converting this script to MySQL 5.6 syntax that will provide the same result.

Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE zip_unique
(     store_nbr integer
     ,zipcode varchar(30)
     ,distance float);
```

Populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO zip_unique (store_nbr, zipcode, distance)
VALUES (123, '76135', 2.356)
     , (456, '76135', 3.002)
     , (789, '76135', 9.521)
```

SQL Server Query to Rank Zipcode based on the distance value:

```
SELECT store_nbr
      ,zipcode
      ,distance
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE
                             ORDER BY DISTANCE) AS ROW_RANK
  FROM zip_unique
```

Output:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
| store_nbr | zipcode | distance | ROW_RANK |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
|       123 |   76135 |    2.356 |        1 |
|       456 |   76135 |    3.002 |        2 |
|       789 |   76135 |    9.521 |        3 |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Please provide DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah (field1 type1, .... );`) and DML (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES (field1_value, .... );`) for your sample tables and data - best in the form of a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk / db-fiddle.com). There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to have a look?

Comment: Absolutely.  Sorry yall!  My newbie is hanging out here.  I will revise this post.

Comment: Ouch -2... I have altered the question hopefully for the better!  Mercy, mercy!

Comment: See my edit to my answer - both work fine since both have window functions albeit much more mature in PostgreSQL  - only arrived in MySQL 8 - I thought it was the result of an "automatic" creation of a table with which you were concerned.

Comment: @BSWarmer - You _may_ want `DENSE_RANK()` or `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` if there can be dups.

Comment: Greatly appreciate all of the feedback and I will look into MariaDB and PostgreSQL as well.  But please keep in mind that this battle at hand is between two existing databases (SQL Server and MySQL).  Adding a 3rd option to the mix is feasible if it is the right move for the long haul... but will be challenging now as both existing databases would have to migrate over.  Again... thanks so much for your feedback!

Comment: The objective in this sample is to get to a single record with Row_RANK = 1 for every zipcode.  Even if there is a tie on the distance, I still want only 1 record selected.  So ROW_NUMBER() is definitely the function that I need (in SQL Server anyways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

(See also the PostgreSQL [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=af6c3e5e2fc7d51f9cc446fc5167b8e6) and MySQL [one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=851ec93f2f41f281b0e90ee59d98040c) with your data)

```
CREATE TABLE zip_unique
(     
  store_nbr integer
  ,zipcode varchar(30)
  ,distance float
);
```

Then populate:

```
INSERT INTO zip_unique (store_nbr, zipcode, distance)
VALUES (123, '76135', 2.356)
     , (456, '76135', 3.002)
     , (789, '76135', 9.521);
```

And then perform the query:

```
SELECT store_nbr
      ,zipcode
      ,distance
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE
                             ORDER BY DISTANCE) AS ROW_RANK
  FROM zip_unique;
```

Result:

```
store_nbr   zipcode     distance    row_rank
      123     76135        2.356           1
      456     76135        3.002           2
      789     76135        9.521           3
```

At @Rick_James ' suggestion, I also ran this:

```
SELECT store_nbr
      ,zipcode
      ,distance
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE
                             ORDER BY DISTANCE) AS ROW_RANK
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE
                             ORDER BY DISTANCE) AS D_RANK
      ,RANK()       OVER(PARTITION BY ZIPCODE
                             ORDER BY DISTANCE) AS R_RANK
  FROM zip_unique;
```

Result

```
store_nbr   zipcode     distance    row_rank    d_rank  r_rank
123     76135   2.356   1   1   1
456     76135   3.002   2   2   2
789     76135   9.521   3   3   3
```

See the PostgreSQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=be0b441627d8242f86533ff29f19d1e0) and the MySQL one [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=449b41d1fa0babae92dab2536f77cc31).

The ranks will vary according to the data - in this case they're the same. This was just to show that PostgreSQL will perform standard Window function code, as does MySQL (PostgreSQL is still the superior db though!).

One of the things I didn't mention previously was PostgreSQL's almost **fanatical** pursuit of the standards laid down by the ISO/ANSII committee on SQL.

---

The following is the answer to the original question - see edits to trace what's gone on prior to the above answer.

You can do the following, (see the MySQL fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c2ac33f8996ea0ff3f613ffb4758d05) and the PostgreSQL one [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=3ceae677dd75939e463e9ffab63f34d9)):

```
CREATE TABLE fred (mary int, paul varchar(20));
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO fred VALUES (1, 'sdf'), (2, 'xxx'), (3, 'yyy');
```

MySQL syntax seems to require this - CTAS, i.e. [`CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ctas%20create%20table%20as) which more or less does what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE bill AS SELECT * FROM fred WHERE mary <= 2;
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM bill;
```

Result:

```
mary    paul
   1     sdf
   2     xxx
```

PostgreSQL does it this way (only differences shown):

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE bill FROM fred WHERE mary <= 2
```

The result is the same.

So, it appears, at least as far as I have been able to determine, that PostgreSQL does **exactly** what you want. MySQL will do the same thing, but it requires a slight (but hardly crippling) change to the syntax of the query. You will see from the fiddles that **both** syntaxes are accepted in PostgreSQL

Comment: You are too kind, thank you sir!  I will have to play with fiddle, first time using that too.  Appreciate the assist for sure!

Comment: You can always upvote and/or mark my answer as correct for this first "port" of one of your queries! :-)

Comment: Don't you love standards; there are so many!  Following a standard is one thing; extending it is, to some extent, the same as violating the standard.  How close is SQL Server to any standard (other than its own)?

Comment: Who likes click-bait?

Comment: @RickJames Standards adherence varies greatly from vendor (anybody who produces a database). I think that PostgreSQL and FirebirdSQL are the closest to the standard. Then maybe Informix? Then Oracle and MS SQL Server and last is MySQL. Check out [this site](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/) - it's fairly good, but is a bit dated. Of course, compliance can get better over time - it's a difficult area in which to be very dogmatic -  intelligent people made various decisions over time. Many comparison sites are rubbish (or [ClickBait](db-engines.com). Still angles, heads of pins &c.

Comment: @Vérace - That site is so old that it should be brought down.  It references MySQL 5.0 which dates back to 2005.  5.1 went GA in 2008.  And MariaDB does a lot better at standards compliance, but it had not spun off by then.

Comment: @RickJames - I know. I did say that adherence to standards varies over time and MySQL with `CTE`s and `Window functions` now is a lot better than it used to be. Still not a patch on PostgreSQL though! :-) I put in `DENSE_RANK()` and `RANK()` as per your suggestion - thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks again to all for support here!  Ultimately this Fiddle website is essential for me to test this and any other queries.  From what I see, it appears that MySQL V8.0 is fully capable of handling this ROW_NUMBER() query.

Answer (score 2):

I asked for it, so I had better answer it...

Based on the data from Vérace, the following should apply to any MySQL >= 4.1 and any MariaDB:

```
SELECT store_nbr,
       zipcode,
       distance,
       @rank := @rank + 1  AS RowRank   -- kludge for numbering the rows
    FROM zip_unique
    JOIN ( SELECT @rank := 0 ) AS init  -- initialization for the kludge
    ORDER BY distance;
```

However, it may not apply to whatever comes after MySQL 8.0 since it sets an @variable in a `SELECT`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question - he wants to know how easy it will be to port MS SQL Server code to MySQL. Does the above construct work with SQL Server? I keep trying to prod the OP towards PostgreSQL but I am also demonstrating that the SQL Server code that he posted can be copied **verbatim** from one server to another - that won't always be the case obviously. Appeciate your input though - +1! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know his real goal.  My example tells him that there is some amount of work to do for _this_ query.  It sounds like he has lots more.  He's aiming at MySQL 5.6; he would be a lot closer with MySQL 8.0 or, better yet, MariaDB 10.2+.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to get a grasp on the magnitude of any switch.  I am currently pleased with SQL Server, but internally another group uses MySQL - there is a push to move to a single database.  I am trying to understand any major ramifications to this move.  This example is simply one query where the ROW_NUMBER)_ over(.... function is utilized.

Comment: @RickJames - Thank you.  Does this script partition by the zipcode?  Meaning if we added a second zipcode to the table (assume 3 more rows) - would the result show Row_Rank values of 1,2,3,4,5,6 or 1,2,3,1,2,3?

Comment: @BSWarmer - That can be done with the aid of a couple more variables.